# conditional count in a list of strings in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle12c

I have list of several items

```
column1 column2                 desired col3  desired col4 
items1  car                     car           1
items2  car,car                 car           2
items3  car,toy,car             toy           1
items4  car,toy,toy             toy           2
items5  car,toy,cards           toy           1
items6  toy,cards,cards         toy           1
items7  toy,cards,toy           toy           2
items8  car,cards,toy,cards     cards         2
items9  car,cards,cards         cards         2
itrmd10 toy,cards,car           toy           1
```

the rule is, if there is a car item then in col3 should come car and count of cars in col4
If there is no car item or another item is present in the list then it should always display the first one that differs form car item + the count of this item.

for example

items3 there is another item as car in the list, in this case toy is the first one, so toy with count 1 will be displayed

items6 there is no car so toy as the first one is displayed

items8 there are another items as car present so the first one is cards this time and will be displayed with count of 2

items10 car needn't be the first item in the list but the rule is the same,another item in the list as car then count the first one = toy with count of 1

thanks

Comment: Your description and sample results don't match.  Several rows have `'car'`, but that is not in the third column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the rule is, if there is a car item then in col3 should come car and count of cars in col4 If there is no car item or another item is present in the list then it should always display the first one that differs form car item + the count of this item.

You can use:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       REGEXP_COUNT(
         ',' || REPLACE( column2, ',', ',,' ) || ',',
         ',' || column3 || ','
       ) AS column4
FROM   (
  SELECT column1,
         column2,
         CASE
         WHEN ',' || column2 || ',' LIKE '%,car,%'
         THEN 'car'
         ELSE REGEXP_SUBSTR( column2, '[^,]+' )
         END AS column3
  FROM   table_name
) t
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( column1, column2 ) AS
SELECT 'items1',  'car'                 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'items2',  'car,car'             FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'items3',  'car,toy,car'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'items4',  'car,toy,toy'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'items5',  'car,toy,cards'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'items6',  'toy,cards,cards'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'items7',  'toy,cards,toy'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'items8',  'car,cards,toy,cards' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'items9',  'car,cards,cards'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'items10', 'toy,cards,car'       FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> COLUMN1 | COLUMN2             | COLUMN3 | COLUMN4
> :------ | :------------------ | :------ | ------:
> items1  | car                 | car     |       1
> items2  | car,car             | car     |       2
> items3  | car,toy,car         | car     |       2
> items4  | car,toy,toy         | car     |       1
> items5  | car,toy,cards       | car     |       1
> items6  | toy,cards,cards     | toy     |       1
> items7  | toy,cards,toy       | toy     |       2
> items8  | car,cards,toy,cards | car     |       1
> items9  | car,cards,cards     | car     |       1
> items10 | toy,cards,car       | car     |       1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=305dbb85ef7f721bda1ada74ec6d72f7)*

---

If you want the first non-`car` item or else `car` if only `car` items then:

```sql
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       column3,
       REGEXP_COUNT( double_delimited, ',' || column3 || ',' ) AS column4
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         CASE
         WHEN REPLACE( double_delimited, ',car,' ) IS NOT NULL
         THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR( REPLACE( double_delimited, ',car,' ), '[^,]+' )
         ELSE 'car'
         END AS column3
  FROM   (
    SELECT column1,
           column2,
           ',' || REPLACE( column2, ',', ',,' ) || ',' AS double_delimited
    FROM   table_name
  ) t
) t
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> COLUMN1 | COLUMN2              | COLUMN3 | COLUMN4
> :------ | :------------------- | :------ | ------:
> items1  | car                  | car     |       1
> items2  | car,car              | car     |       2
> items3  | car,toy,car          | toy     |       1
> items4  | car,toy,toy          | toy     |       2
> items5  | car,toy,cards        | toy     |       1
> items6  | toy,cards,cards      | toy     |       1
> items7  | toy,cards,toy        | toy     |       2
> items8  | car,cards,toy,cards  | cards   |       2
> items9  | car,cards,cards      | cards   |       2
> items10 | toy,cards,car        | toy     |       1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0176b3b4afc1e5ac86fd772c49323435)*

Comment: hi, is not correct, the rule is if there is car only then you count cars but if there is another item doesn't matter at which place you should count that item which comes as first.items8,9,10 there are another items present in the string,look what should be there

Comment: @Pato That is not what the question asks. The question states "if there is a car item then in col3 should come car and count of cars in col4". Items 8, 9 and 10 have a `car` item so then `column3` should be `car`. This answers the question **as asked**.

Comment: yes but the next sentece is - If there is no car item OR another item is present in the list then it should always display the first one that differs form car item + the count of this item.. therefore I provide the desired output to be more clear,sorry if it is confusing